# Issue with 'Having trunc' clause in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've a small SQL query which is used to run in an Oracle DB and fetches some result.

**Now this query works fine SQL 2000 but NOT in SQL 2008.** i.e. SQL 2000 returns more than 10k results compared to zero result of SQL 2008.

When I went in depth I found, last line `HAVING  trunc(MIN(processed_date)) Between ''01-Sep-2005'' And ''01-Oct-2005''` makes all the difference. If I remove this line in both the versions, results are all the same. Please suggest an alternative for this road block, so that I get the same results in 2008 ver. as I get in 2000 ver.

```
Select *       
FROM OPENQUERY( ORAXYZ, '           
  SELECT    DISTINCT(file_num),           
            to_char(MIN(Processed_date), ''YYYYMMDD'') Processed_date, 
            to_char(MIN(Report_Date), ''YYYYMMDD'') Report_Date,
            file_stmt           

  FROM FILE_RECORDS         

  GROUP BY file_num, file_stmt  
  --processed_date value is truncated to date portion          
  HAVING  trunc(MIN(processed_date)) Between ''01-Sep-2005'' And ''01-Oct-2005'' 
')
```

Comment: Are they pointing to the same oracle server?  That query runs on the remote end, so the SQL version shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes Stanley, there are indeed pointing to same oracle server.

Comment: @Kings how about the properties of the linked server?, is the user the same?, how about the language?. You could also try changing your `HAVING` to `to_char(MIN(processed_date),''yyyymmdd'') BETWEEN ''20050901'' And ''20051001''`

Comment: 'to_char' is not executing in place of 'Having trunc'. I may be missing something. Properties, user, language etc stays same in both the cases of SQL versions.

Comment: @Kings I don't understand why `to_char` isn't executing, you are using it on the `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

```
HAVING CAST( MIN(processed_date) AS Date) BETWEEN '2005-09-01' AND '2005-10-01'
```

Comment: No success. Query is still returning zeros rows in SQL 2008.